# Complex number, strangely written

Tags: calculus, analysis, complex-numbers

Find all the complex solutions of the equation:

$$\frac{z^3}{i} = 1$$

I mean is this the same thing as $$z^3 = i$$?

Because I don't understand why my teacher would put it like that on a test. At this level of mathematics we should obviously know how to re-arrange variables in such a simple equation..

Comment: Well, $i$ isn't a variable. Is this part of a longer series of questions? You could also note that $(-i)^3=i$ and use that instead.

Comment: Not really. Before this one it just said: Find the solutions of $$z^4 = 4$$

Comment: Yes it is the same, and I don't understand why your teacher would put it like that either ;-)

Comment: Your teacher is probably testing whether you understand complex numbers - why not put it on a test?

Comment: Yes, just because one problem is in the form $z^n = k$, why should all be? You should not just be learning to solve equations by rote, only knowing how to deal with one format. I have rarely seen $i$ come up in the denominator of a ratio in practice, but if you ever do see it, you should know what to do about it.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\frac{1}{i} = -i$.  So $\frac{z^3}{i} = -iz^3$.  From here, you can just multiply both sides by $i$.  In short, you are correct, and it is indeed strange that it was written like that on your exam.

Comment: You might as well multiply both sides of the original equation by $i$, without the detour via $-i$.

Comment: Basically, yes.